# Hide/ Disable mic option from android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I want to hide the mic from soft keyboard in my current application.

I have tried these possible solutions for the same.

[Disable speech to text button (Micro phone) on soft input keyboard in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263554/disable-speech-to-text-button-micro-phone-on-soft-input-keyboard-in-android-pr)

But this solution is not working at all.

I found one unexpected thing, when add the inputType = “textFilter” then it works for me, I mean the mic is getting hidden.

But If possible then I want to have the exact solution for the problem, because If I adopt the mentioned “textFilter” thing then later times it may break.

I have tried on below O.S. versions

1. Pie(API-28), Device - Pixel2XL
2. Marshmallow(API-23), Device - MotoE3Power

Answer (score 1):

You can also define **android:privateImeOptions="nm"** in XML where **nm = [no microphone]**:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:id="@+id/email"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:privateImeOptions="nm" />
```

Comment: I checked on both API level as u mentioned in question

Comment: I think this both solution are working on Samsung but not in Motorola and Google Pixel devices as I mentioned.

Comment: Worked for me, too.  Samsung Note 9