# How to remove speech to text (mic) from Google Keyboard in NativeScript?

Tags: android, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have tried a few options available in the following links.
1. [Disable speech to text button (Micro phone) on soft input keyboard in android programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263554/disable-speech-to-text-button-micro-phone-on-soft-input-keyboard-in-android-pr)
2. [How to disable displaying "suggestions" on the Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281838/how-to-disable-displaying-suggestions-on-the-soft-keyboard/5039551)

doesn't seem to work.

`<TextField
              fieldFocusClass
              returnKeyType="done"
              autocorrect="false"
              formControlName="pin"
            >
            </TextField>`

Answer (score 0):

Well `privateImeOptions` doesn't seem to work with current version of Android. You could set input type to `TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD`

**HTML**

```
<TextField (loaded)="onLoaded($event)"></TextField>
```

**TS**

```
onLoaded(event) {
    const textField = event.object;
    if (textField.android) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            textField.android.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

**Note:** If you like to avoid timeout, you might want to extend existing textfield to create your own that applies custom input type.